# AngularJS & Typescript: How to assign a class/type as a directive's controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-controller

AngularJS directives specify a controller using:

```
{
  controller: function ($scope){}
}
```

As of yet, I have not found a way where I can create a TypeScript class and assign it to a directive's controller property.

What I would like to do is something like

```
interface IDirectiveController{
    myProperty:string;
}

class DirectiveController implements IDirectiveController{
   static $injector = [$scope];
   constructor ($scope:ng.IScope){
       this.myProperty = 'default';
   }

   public myProperty:string;
}


var directive:ng.IDirective =
{
   controller:DirectiveController;
}
return directive;
```

Better yet, it would be nice if a factory function could be used that would let me create and return a new instance of the controller, similar to how the directive itself is instantiated.

In my directive template I would also like to bind directly to the controller rather than having to assign the properties of the class to $scope.

Another way of stating this might be to say, I would like to be able to assign controllers to directives in a manner similar to assigning a controller using the `myController as ContollerType` syntax that is available in a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could do something like this in your directive:

```
...
controller: DirectiveController,
controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
...
```

Then angular should instantiate your class with its constructor and you can refer to it in the template with `myCtrl`

Comment: Wow, that is buried in the documentation.   If you google:
"controllerAs" site:angularjs.org
you only get $route and $compile documentation.  It is however discussed in many other places, particularly on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yep I looked for doc on it and only found a tiny paragraph that didn't really explain it. Had to search StackOverflow to get an example of it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply do what you would do in the absence of a directive i.e. :

```
class DirectiveController{
   static $inject = ['$scope']; // fixed a few typos here
   constructor ($scope){
       $scope.vm = this;        // this is the pattern I recommend for all controllers
       this.myProperty = 'default';
   }

   public myProperty:string;
}
```

To learn more about this pattern see : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Comment: I forgot about the the old method of adding the controller to the scope this way.  I didn't start using AngularJS until they already had the as keyword for controller assignment.  Great videos by the way basarat.  I'll have to go back and see if you have any new ones since I last looked.  I would never have gotten as far with typescript/angular without them.   You should approach Pluralsight to put together a fully produced course.  The controllerAs option is the cleaner (or at least more declarative) way of doing this so I am marking that one as the answer.